# How to enable gzip compression for specific URL

Tags: gzip

How can I enable gzip compression for a specific URL link like this :
https://www.examples.com/compress.css

I tried :

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
</IfModule>
```

But it not works. Please advise.